# Why does json.Unmarshal work with reference but not pointer?

Tags: json, go

This example from the [json.Unmarshal](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) docs (slightly modified for simplicity to use `Animal` instead of `[]Animal`) works, no errors:

[Playground link of working example](http://play.golang.org/p/dFeihe9DUc)

```
// ...
var animals Animal
err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &animals)
// ...
```

But this slightly modified example doesn't:

[Playground link of non-working example](http://play.golang.org/p/T33L87SbWi)

```
// ...
var animals *Animal
err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, animals)
// ...
```

It displays this obscure error that really isn't helpful (looks more like a function call than an error IMO):

> json: Unmarshal(nil *main.Animal)

This appears to be because `animals` is an uninitialized pointer. But the docs say (emphasis mine):

> Unmarshal unmarshals the JSON into the value pointed at by the pointer. **If the pointer is nil, Unmarshal allocates a new value for it to point to.**

So why does unmarshaling fail in the second example and show that obscure error?

(Also, is it "unmarshalling" or "unmarshaling" (one L)? The docs use both.)

Comment: On the spelling issue, British English uses double 'l' for marshalled and marshalling (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/marshal) but American English does not.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You've encountered an [InvalidUnmarshalError](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#InvalidUnmarshalError) (see [lines 109 and 110 in decode.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/json/decode.go?s=3588:3724#L109)).

> // An InvalidUnmarshalError describes an invalid argument passed to Unmarshal.
>   // **(The argument to Unmarshal must be a non-nil pointer.)**

It seems the docs could do with some clarification as the quote above and the comment below [from the `Unmarshal` source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/json/decode.go?s=905:1025#L34) seem to contradict each other.

> If the pointer is nil, Unmarshal allocates a new value for it to point to.

Answer (score 54):

Because your pointer is nil.

If you initialize it it works: http://play.golang.org/p/zprmV0O1fG

```
var animals *Animal = &Animal{}
```

Also, it can be spelled either way (consistency in a single doc would be nice, though): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)

Comment: Okay, but then what does this mean in the documentation for Unmarshal: "If the pointer is nil, Unmarshal allocates a new value for it to point to." Why do we have to initialize it if Unmarshal should be doing it for us?

Comment: Haha, yeah I just saw that in your question. Well, if you pass in the reference to the pointer, it also allocates it. http://play.golang.org/p/3KP7pPKmBp

Comment: Interesting. So is my understanding of what "pointer" means incorrect or are the docs wrong? Because all I see working here are references, not pointers.

Comment: It wouldn't be able to change the value of the pointer (where it's pointing to), without a reference to the pointer.

Comment: Perhaps the documentation about allocating a new value for pointers refers to the behavior when populating a struct with pointer fields rather than the pointer passed to Unmarshal. Consider that Unmarshal has no way to return the new pointer to the caller as the passed pointer cannot be modified by Unmarshal.

Comment: Well, it does allocate if you give it a reference to a pointer--maybe they should just clarify what it expects for that case in the doc. Also, hi Chris from the meetup!

Comment: @EveFreeman I don't think this is a "reference to a pointer" (which I take to mean something like `int** a` in C). 

I think that both the reference and the pointer way are the same, but when you get the address of an existing object (the reference way), it will not be `nil`

Answer (score 21):

I believe the issue is that, while you can pass a *pointer to nil* to Unmarshal(), you can't pass a *nil pointer value*.

A pointer to nil would be like:

```
var v interface{}
json.Unmarshal(text, &v)
```

The value of `v` is nil, but the pointer to `v` is a non-zero pointer address.  It's a non-zero pointer, which is pointing to a nil interface{} (which itself is a pointer type).  Unmarshal doesn't return an error in this case.

A nil pointer would be like:

```
var v *interface{}
json.Unmarshal(text, v)
```

In this case, the type of v is `pointer to an interface{}`, but as with any declaration of a var in golang, the initial value of `v` is the type's zero-value.  So `v` is a zero-value pointer, which means it isn't pointing to any valid place in memory.

As mentioned in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/20478917/387176, json.Unmarshal() needs a valid pointer to *something*, so it can change the something (be it a zero value struct, or a pointer) in place.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar condition before but in a different case.
It is related with concept of interface in Go.
If a function declares a interface as argument or return value, **the caller have to pass or return the reference**

In your case, `json.Unmarshal` accept interface as second argument